# Can't select my block by clicking on it on apiVersion - but using blockProps

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I'm building my first Wordpress block but I've ran into an issue. If I set my block's apiVersion to 2, I am not able to select my block.

I'm aware that for apiVersion 2, you need to use the useBlockProps hook.

Below is the source for my blocks edit and save functions.

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";

import {
  useBlockProps,
  InnerBlocks,
  InspectorControls,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";

import { GradientPicker, PanelBody, PanelRow } from "@wordpress/components";

const Edit = (props) => {
  const {
    attributes: { gradient },
    setAttributes,
  } = props;

  const blockProps = useBlockProps();

  const onChangeGradient = (newGradient) => {
    setAttributes({ gradient: newGradient });
  };

  return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
      <div style={{ "--gradient": gradient }}>
        <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={["core/paragraph", "core/heading"]} />
      </div>
      <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody title={__("Gradient Settings")}>
          <PanelRow>
            <GradientPicker
              value={gradient}
              gradients={[]}
              onChange={onChangeGradient}
            />
          </PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Edit;
```

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

const Save = (props) => {

  const {
    attributes: { gradient },
  } = props;
  const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

  return (
    <div {...blockProps} style={{ "--gradient": gradient }}>
      <InnerBlocks.Content />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Save;
```

These are used to register the block in my index.js

```
import json from './block.json';
import edit from './edit';
import save from './save';

import './style.css';
import './editor.css';

// Destructure the json file to get the name and settings for the block
// For more information on how this works, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
const { name } = json;

// Register the block
registerBlockType( name, {
    edit, // Object shorthand property - same as writing: edit: edit,
    save, // Object shorthand property - same as writing: save: save,
} );
```

Here's my block.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "name": "custom-block-plugin/gradient-text",
  "title": "Gradient Text",
  "textdomain": "custom-block-plugin",
  "icon": "admin-appearance",
  "category": "layout",
  "attributes": {
    "gradient": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "linear-gradient(90deg, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12)"
    }
  },
  "example": {
    "attributes": {
      "gradient": "linear-gradient(90deg, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12)"
    }
  },
  "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
  "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out, just needed clickable area like some padding or something to get this to be clickable since the InnerBlock doesn't behave like normal elements. There's also a button to click on the InnerBlocks wrapper, so I'll probably be leaving this block as is.